# Default login page in web.api 2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to create a new web.api project using this guide:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

Now on my good old webforms project I could set a page that would show if the user was'nt logged in, no matter what the user would try to access.

Can a web.api project be configured to do the same (show a default login-page no matter the path written in the URL) and off course show the correct page when the user IS authenticated?

Answer (score 0):

You should use Authorization for token.

During creating project select Individual User Accounts.

[image]

And, Project will be installed Microsoft identity framework.
You can use `Authorize` attiribute.

```
 [Authorize]
    public class TestController : ApiController
    {
    }
```

After registering, send login request this **http://localhost:fooPortNumber/token** link.

The request will contain the token information.

You should send token information to controller.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I wasnt asking how to use authentication, but if it was possible to have the system (the controllers) display a default login page when users are not logged in.  It can be coded I know, but isnt there any build-in functionality for this; like in forms-authentication.